# Which properties does the box topology conserve?

Tags: general-topology, box-topology

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) on the Product topology has a wealth of examples of properties conserved by the product topology.

The following is a quote from the linked article:

"

**Separation**

- Every product of T0 spaces is T0
- Every product of T1 spaces is T1
- Every product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff
- Every product of regular spaces is regular
- Every product of Tychonoff spaces is Tychonoff

**Compactness**
Every product of compact spaces is compact (Tychonoff's theorem)

"

I know that Tychconoff's theorem doesn't hold for the box topology, i.e. the product of compact spaces with the box topology is not compact.
Which, if any, of the other properties above is conserved by the product topology?

Note, that since the box topology and the product topology are identical in the finite case, all of the above are true for the box topology in the finite case.

Comment: I'd guess the separation ones

Comment: @miraunpajaro. Separation up to being Tychonoff. Normality ($T_4$) is not even preserved by finite products. It is an open question whether the box product  $\Bbb R^{\aleph_0}$ is a  normal space.

Comment: It may be anecdotical, but a product of Alexandroff topologies is an Alexandroff topology with the box topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It preserves the separation axioms up to Tychonoff.

In the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology there is a chapter by Scott S. Williams on box products with the theorem:

> If $X_i, i \in I$ are non-discrete, Hausdorff completely regular spaces then for an infinite index set $I$ $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ in the box topology (also denoted $\Box_{i \in I} X_i$) is not 
>   i) locally compact or compact
>   (ii) separable 
>   (iii) connected or locally connected
>   (iv) first countable
>   (v) perfect (=closed sets are $G_\delta$)

So box product are never very "nice", and a nice source of possible counterexamples. The first found ZFC [Dowker space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowker_space) is a subspace of a box product e.g.

Comment: Is it still an open Q whether the box product $\Bbb R^{\aleph_0}$ is normal?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes it is still open AFAIK.

Comment: To the proposer: The proofs for the separation axioms are almost the same as for the Tychonoff-product.